# Awesomium 1.7. How change awesomium browser version?

Tags: awesomium

Javascript detect awesomium browser like Chrome browser Version 18.0.1003.1
Can I configure awesomium browser version like on my machine or Chrome 22 or later?
I need this for supporting touch events on javascript.

Answer (score 7):

You can't change the version of Chrome that Awesomium uses. All you can do is make sure you are using the latest version of Awesomium.

The current version of Awesomium (1.7) uses Chrome 18.

Comment: Yes you can.  Configure your particular user agent needs with WebCore.Initialize

Comment: The question isn't asking how to change the UserAgent. I added a comment to your answer.